# Android google signin API get the phone number

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to get the phone number of a user when he uses the google sign in API for android so I can save it but I cannot find any reference or documentation to achieve this. Is this possible? Has any one done it?

I am using the example from android dev docs with

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

All working as onActivityResult I can do:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString("name", account.getDisplayName());
            edit.putString("middlename", account.getGivenName());
            edit.putString("surname", account.getFamilyName());
            edit.putString("dialprefix", AppConstants.getCountryPrefix());
            edit.putString("phone", );
            edit.putString("email", account.getEmail());
            edit.putString("myUUID", myUUID);
```

The missing part is the phone number.

Comment: I'm not sure , but i think you cannot get user's phone number, due to privacy purpose.

Comment: `GoogleSignInOptions` is limited to some essentials details which certainly not have the mobile number . I don't think it provides the Phone Number at all with some Other API or Scope too . Have a look at [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)  See what you can get from it..

Comment: Thanks. Checked People API too and it doesn't seem to allow this. I guess I will have to manually request the number.